# Problems with conditional rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-statements

I'm trying to mark divs that is clicked on my website. When I click, the array is updated but the mark won't show. It seems like the statement `gameChoices.includes('Fortnite')` is false, even though the array contains the exact value `Fortnite`.

Does anyone know why this happens? Eventually a new solution for the problem?

Code:

```
<Container onClick={() => {
  if (gameChoices.includes('Fortnite')) {
    const findIndex = gameChoices.findIndex(a => a === 'Fortnite')

    findIndex !== -1 && gameChoices.splice(findIndex , 1)
  } else if (gameChoices.includes('Fortnite') === false) {
    gameChoices.push('Fortnite')
  }
}} fluid className="d-flex fortnite gameoption position-relative">
  {gameChoices.includes('Fortnite') ? 
    <>
      <BsCheckSquare color="lightgreen" size="2rem" style={{ top: '50%', right: '50%' }} />
    </>
    : null
  }
  <h1 className="fw-bolder text-light text-center m-auto">FORTNITE</h1>
</Container>
```

```
const [gameChoices, setGameChoices] = useState([])
```

[image: gameChoices data]

Comment: can you add the gameChoices data ?

Comment: 2 Suggestions. Do not use inline click handler. It makes your markup difficult to read. `findIndex !== -1` is not required as you are already checking if it is included in array.

Comment: You can also add some log statements and see what the contents of gameChoices is.

Comment: Also `gameChoices.includes('Fortnite') === false` is redundant. Just a simple else is enough

Comment: `gameChoises` probably isn't a state variable, update your code to make it a state with the `useState()` hook

Comment: when the div is clicked, the content of gameChoices is ```['Fortnite']```

Comment: @DanielOlsen is it a state variable?

Comment: I've added more relevant info to the question, the const and data outputed when clicked on the div

Comment: @DanielOlsen in order to make the template update it's content you need to update a state variable, now, if `gameChoises` is a state (and now we know it is), you must update it by using it's `setter` function if you want it to dispatch the event, you can't just update the state variable directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have commented:

> - Do not use inline click handler. It makes your markup difficult to read.
> - findIndex !== -1 is not required as you are already checking if it is included in array
> - Also gameChoices.includes('Fortnite') === false is redundant. Just a simple else is enough

But in addition to this, you need to set value to state.

Apart from that, you should instead look into `.some` and check for same cased text. You can in addition do trim if game name is coming from user input

```js
const choiceExists = (game) => {
    return gameChoices.some(
    (name) => name.toLowerCase() === game.toLowerCase()
  )
}
const clickHandler = () => {
    const name = 'fortnite'
  if (choiceExists(name)) {
    const newGames = gameChoices.filter((game) => game.toLowerCase() !== name)
    setGameChoices(newGames)
  } else {
    setGameChoices((choices) => choices.concat(name))
  }
}

<Container onClick={clickHandler} fluid className="d-flex fortnite gameoption position-relative">
  {
    gameChoices.includes('Fortnite')
      ? <BsCheckSquare
          color="lightgreen"
          size="2rem"
          style={{ top: '50%', right: '50%' }} />
      : null
  }
  <h1 className="fw-bolder text-light text-center m-auto">FORTNITE</h1>
</Container>
```

Comment: It worked like a charm! Looks like your solution with filter worked better, since it isn't stuck at ```false``` now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you update a reactive state value you should use the state setter method, so `setGameChoices((choices)=>[...choices, 'Fortnite'])`